# Slashes appear in displayed form text despite using stripslashes

Tags: php, mysql, stripslashes

I have a comment box form up and running, and I just noticed that when I use `'` it creates a `\` in front of it. For example, if I write "how's" it shows up as "how\'s" both in the database it's posting to and when it displays on the page. I'm using  the `stripslashes` function when I display the "body" text, which I thought was supposed to get rid of slashes.

My server is running php version 5.3.6, if that helps.

I'm using this piece of code to post the text from the body of the comment box into my database:

```
$body = mysql_prep($_POST['body']);
```

The function it is using is this:

```
function mysql_prep($string) {
    global $connection;

    $escaped_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $string);
    return $escaped_string;
}
```

Side note: you don't need to answer this, but that's the function I'm using to make the text users enter safe from hackers, baddies, and all that. Am I doing that alright or am I am leaving myself open to issues? (besides this slash problem that might be because of this function)

This is the code I'm using to display the text:

```
<div id="comments">
    <?php while($comment_text = mysqli_fetch_assoc($display_comments)) { ?>
    <div class="comment" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
        <div class="author">
            <b><?php echo htmlentities($comment_text["author"]); ?>:</b>
        </div>
        <div class="meta-info" style="font-size: 0.8em;">
            <?php echo datetime_to_text($comment_text["created"]); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <?php echo stripslashes($comment_text["body"], '<strong><em><p>'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>  
    <?php if(empty($display_comments)) { echo "No Comments."; } ?>
</div>
```

Any help or advice is super appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: I don't see `stripslashes()`. I only see `strip_tags()` (which does something else).

Comment: You won't need the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function when preparing a MySQLi query.

Comment: oh dang, ur right @Gerald Schneider! I guess I'll just take that out and put in stripslashes instead? Unless I'm messing something up by doing that...

Comment: Actually, I just tried switching it out, I'm still getting slashes... but I'll update my question to reflect that now

Comment: What does it return `var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc())`? True or false?

Comment: @djay sorry if this sounds dumb, but how do I get it to tell me true or false after I put in the function?

Comment: Sounds like you have Magic Quotes turned on. You can create `test.php` (or something like that) then put one line there `var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc())`, then run that script. It would output either true or false

Comment: @djay I got "int(1)" as the result, so I guess that's true. How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that, you have [Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on. You can recursively strip all slashes using this approach:

File `magic_quotes_filter.php`

```
<?php

if (function_exists('set_magic_quotes_runtime') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

    function stripslashes_deep($value) {
        $value = is_array($value) ?
                    array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                    stripslashes($value);

        return $value;
    }

    $_POST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_POST);
    $_GET = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_GET);
    $_COOKIE = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_COOKIE);
    $_REQUEST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_REQUEST);  
}
```

Then yon can simply `include('path/to/magic_quotes_filter.php')` where you deal with request HTTP variables.

In your case, just include it at the top of your script.